# Reading an Rank 2 array in FORTRAN 95

Tags: arrays, fortran

I want to read an array from a text file
it looks like this

```
1   88  90  94  102 111 122 134
2   75  77  80   86  94 103 113
3   80  83  85   94 100 111 121 
4   68  71  76   85  96 110 125
5   77  84  91   98 105 112 119
6   81  85  90   96 102 109 120
```

(above data is  6 by 8 matrix, evenly spaced, it might not show up correctly

my code

```
program cool
implicit none
integer:: ok(6,8),k,i
open(unit = 1, file = "a.txt")
read(1,*) ok
Write(*,*) ok
print*,ok_1(4,3)
end program cool
```

the issue i am having is that ok(4,3) does not correspond to 71 ( 4th row down ,3rd column)

I have tried to read the file such as
read(unit =1,10) ok
10 format ( 8(i4))

! i have tried variants of this

What ever way i try, calling ok(i,j) does not correspond to the value i need

I need this for find the row averages and column averages with out column one included. This is simple with Do loops as long as I can get the correct values, which i can not

edit::
I have also tried to hard code the array in my program
ok = reshape((/1,88,90,94,102,111,122,134,&
2,75,77,80,86 ,94 ,103,113,&
3,80,83,85,94 ,100,111,121,&
4,68,71,76,85 ,96 ,110,125,&
5,77,84,91,98 ,105,112,119,&
6,81,85,90,96 ,102,109,120/),(/6,8/)) however this also does not seem to make the correspond aswell ok(4,4) returns 100 not 76

Answer (score 2):

Fortran stores its arrays in memory in *column-major* order, so element `ok(1,1)` is followed by element `ok(2,1), ok(3,1), ...` and so on.  The convenient statement

```
read(1,*) ok
```

reads the numbers into the array in that order.  Using `reshape` on the same list of elements results in the same array.

Perhaps you thought the array would be stored in *row-major* order, `ok(1,1), ok(1,2), ok(1,3), ...` ?

You could either read the file line by line, something like

```
do ix = 1, 6
   read(1,*) ok(ix,:)
end do
```

or read the file in one gulp into an `8*6` temporary array and transpose it.  Or you could re-order the elements in the file.